# no matches for kind "ClusterRbacConfig" in version "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, rbac

I've been trying to complete the first step of https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authz-http/. With the following file, i'm supposed to activate authorization on the default namespace of my cluster.

However, when i run the following script:

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ClusterRbacConfig
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  mode: 'ON_WITH_INCLUSION'
  inclusion:
    namespaces: ["default"]
```

which is an exact copy of the script on the website, i get the following error:
`error: unable to recognize "5-authorization/yaml-files/rbac-config-ON.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRbacConfig" in version "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"`.

Unless istio's documentation is severely out-of-date, and the apiVersion is no longer the correct one, i don't know what causes this.

Comment: It seems to work fine with the fresh installation of Istio 1.2.3. How did you install Istio? Have the CRDs been created correctly? You can verify if the `ClusterRbacConfig` CRD exists by running: `kubectl get crd clusterrbacconfigs.rbac.istio.io`.

Comment: Istio was installed by default in GKE, which uses Istio 1.2.2, and that (apparently) does not include the ClusterRbacConfig CRD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [szymig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7298328/szymig) mentioned, the wrong version of Istio was used. GKE runs 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You probably installed Istio in a bad way. If you install Istio using helm, you need to install CRD first [istio-crd](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/#installation-steps).

So just check it executing command:

```
$ kubectl get crd
```

in istio namespace.

Make sure you have all CRD degined here: [istio-crd-definitions](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init/files/crd-10.yaml).

Deploying the **istio.yaml** twice seems to be working. BUT you have to wait a little between the two runs.

if as browning said the certs must be deployed first, then it make sense that its working on the second run.